# How can I list all Ruby classes instantiated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to list all classes instantiated during one Ruby on Rails API query.

Is there a benchmarking tool or a profiler I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`Object_space#each_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object):

```
ObjectSpace.each_object.to_a
```

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to ndn's answer:

[ObjectSpace#each_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) allows you to iterate through all instances of a specific class. For example:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(String) do |object|
  p object
end
```

[ObjectSpace#count_objects](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-count_objects) shows number of instances of each class.

```
p ObjectSpace.count_objects

# Result:
# {:TOTAL=>30163,
#  :FREE=>1007,
#  :T_OBJECT=>39,
#  :T_CLASS=>534,
#  :T_MODULE=>24,
```

Check out [this wonderful repository](https://github.com/franzejr/best-ruby) for more useful ruby tricks.